# Uploadify file uploading

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

i am trying to use uploadify, to upload pdf or txt files, but without success. Uploadify 2.1.4 uploads just image files. I tried to just rename file extensions, tried to allow *.*, tried to namely allow pdf or other formats, but Uploadify uploads just F******g images and i do not know why...

Please help me.

I use these settings:

```
public function show()
{
        if(!$this->dir) throw new exception("Upload dir is not set");
        if(!$this->url) throw new exception("Upload url is not set");

        $rem=(isset($_POST[$this->name."-rem"]))?$_POST[$this->name."-rem"]:"";
        $tpl='<div id="'.$this->name.'-queue" class="upload-queue">'.$this->fillQueue().'</div>';
        $tpl.='<input id="'.$this->name.'-uploadify" name="'.$this->name.'-uploadify" type="file" />';
        $tpl.='<input id="'.$this->name.'-files" name="'.$this->name.'-files" type="hidden" />';
        $tpl.='<input id="'.$this->name.'-rem" name="'.$this->name.'-rem" type="hidden" value="'.$rem.'"/>';
        //$tpl.='<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/uploadify/uploadify.css" />';
        $tpl.="<script type=\"text/javascript\"><!--
        var ".$this->name."Files=".$this->currentCount.";
        function ".$this->name."DeleteFile(where)
        {
            var rem=$('#".$this->name."-rem').val();
            if(rem!='') rem+=',';
            $('#".$this->name."-rem').val(rem+$(where).parent().attr('id'));
            $(where).parent().remove();
            ".$this->name."Files--;
            if(".$this->name."Files<".$this->count.") $(\"#".$this->name."-uploadifyUploader\").show();
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(\"#".$this->name."-uploadify\").uploadify({
            'uploader'       : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script'         : '".$this->url."',
            'scriptData'     : {'".session_name()."':'".session_id()."'},
            'cancelImg'      : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'folder'         : '".$this->dir."/thumb',
            'queueID'        : '".$this->name."-queue',
            'auto'           : true,
            'multi'          : ".(($this->count>1)?"true":"false").",
            'buttonText'     : '".$this->buttonName."',
            'fileExt'        : '".rtrim($this->fileExt,";")."',
            'fileDesc'       : '".rtrim($this->fileDesc,",")."',
            onError          : function (a, b, c, d) {
                                 if (d.status == 404)
                                    alert('Could not find upload script. Use a path relative to: '+'<?= getcwd() ?>');
                                 else if (d.type === \"HTTP\")
                                    alert('error '+d.type+\": \"+d.status);
                                 else if (d.type ===\"File Size\")
                                    alert(c.name+' '+d.type+' Limit: '+Math.round(d.sizeLimit/1024)+'KB');
                                 else
                                    alert('error '+d.type+\": \"+d.text);
                                },
            onComplete       : function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data){
                                $(\"#".$this->name."-queue\").append('<div id=\"'+fileObj.filePath+'\" class=\"item\"><div style=\"background: url('+fileObj.filePath+') no-repeat 50% 50%\"></div><img src=\"/uploadify/cancel.png\" class=\"delete-file\" onclick=\"".$this->name."DeleteFile(this);\"></div>');
                                $('#".$this->name."-queue').sortable('refresh');
                                ".$this->name."Files++;
                                if(".$this->name."Files>=".$this->count.") $(\"#".$this->name."-uploadifyUploader\").hide();
                                },
            onInit           : function(){setTimeout(function(){if(".$this->name."Files>=".$this->count.") $(\"#".$this->name."-uploadifyUploader\").hide();},500);}
        });
    $('#".$this->name."-queue').sortable();
    $('#".$this->name."-queue').disableSelection();
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('#".$this->name."-files').val($('#".$this->name."-queue').sortable('toArray'));
    });
});
--></script>";

        return array("",$tpl);
    }
```

...

Thank you!

Comment: You kind of intertwine PHP and JS there. Which one is giving you the errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your current options to these:

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg'   : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'      : '/uploads',
    'fileTypeExt'     : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',  <== this line
    'fileTypeDesc'    : 'Image Files'
});
```

For reference: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/filetypeexts/

Comment: i know that there is fileExt flag, i tried remove it, i tried rewrite it to pdf,doc,docx etc., but it only image files uploads, nothing else... that is why i wrote here for help...

Comment: first demo uploads *.*, but i do not know if it is on that server succesfuly uploaded, and second demo uploads just images, but it is set to upload images only...

Comment: @[Efazati]This will also upload .txt files when 'Image' is selected as the file type. How do you allow selection of .txt files when 'File' is selected as the file type?

Answer (score 0):

Use `'fileExt'               : '*.pdf;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png',` instead of the filename that reads it.

Comment: @[pufos]This will also upload .txt files when 'Image' is selected as the file type. How do you allow selection of .txt files when 'File' is selected as the file type?

Answer (score 0):

```
var settingObject = {
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',   // set your path
    'checkScript':'/uploadify/check.php',    // set your path
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',   // set your path
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',   // set your path
    'folder'    : '/files/useruploads',
    'auto'      : true,
    'fileExt'   : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.txt;*.pdf;*.doc;*.docx',   // any extension you want to allow
    'fileDesc'  : 'Upload Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG, .TXT, .PDF, .DOC, .DOCX)',
    'removeCompleted': false
  };

$("#file-1").uploadify(settingObject);
```

Reference : (File-Extension) http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/fileext/

This should work for you..

Comment: @[Muneer]This will also upload .txt files when 'Image' is selected as the file type. How do you allow selection of .txt files when 'File' is selected as the file type?

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines:

```
'fileTypeExt'        : '*.txt;*.pdf;',
'fileTypeDesc'       : '*.txt and *.pdf',
```

Comment: @[Somnath Muluk] This will also upload .txt files when 'Image' is selected as the file type. How do you allow selection of .txt files when 'File' is selected as the file type?

Comment: @Zesty:he said "i am trying to use uploadify, to upload pdf or txt files" so allowed file extensions should be .txt, .pdf

Comment: @[Somnath Muluk] I was not disagreeing with your solution. I was just asking if you know how to add more than one file type, as an array or something. It would be nice to be able to have more than one choice in the dropdown. I'm not sure if that's possible, though.

Comment: @Zesty: yes you are correct. required file types are needs to be mentioned in 'fileExt'. it is not possible by giving array i think so.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue of Size Limit for each file. Try adding the following

```
'sizeLimit': 500000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit `upload_max_filesize` in your `php.ini`